# Pull text from webpage and trim

Tags: shell, trim

```
wget --output-document=- http://www.tip.it/runescape/grand-exchange-centre 2>/dev/null \
| grep "The Grand Exchange updated" \
```

Will output something like:

```
<h4 id="gec_update_time">The Grand Exchange updated <span><b>1</b> days, <b>12</b> hours, <b>45</b> minutes and <b>1</b> seconds ago</span></h4>
```

My goal was to trim it up so it would only output:

```
1 days, 12 hours, 45 minutes, 1 seconds
```

Not exactly that great with it, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an option to use lynx, you get this for free:

```
$ lynx -dump http://www.tip.it/runescape/grand-exchange-centre | grep "The Grand Exchange updated"
The Grand Exchange updated 1 days, 19 hours, 8 minutes and 48 seconds ago
```

From there you can strip the leading text, if required:

```
$ foo="$(lynx -dump http://www.tip.it/runescape/grand-exchange-centre | grep "The Grand Exchange updated")"
$ echo "${foo#*updated }"
1 days, 19 hours, 9 minutes and 8 seconds ago
```

If you absolutely want to use wget and strip out the tags, you can use something like this:

```
$ wget --output-document=- http://www.tip.it/runescape/grand-exchange-centre 2>/dev/null | grep "The Grand Exchange updated" | sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>//g' -e 's/The Grand Exchange updated //'
1 days, 19 hours, 17 minutes and 2 seconds ago
```

The first option is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a short Ruby script:

`gem install sanitize`

Make a file called "cleaner.rb":

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
require 'rubygems'
require 'sanitize'

puts Sanitize.clean(gets).trim
```

And then...

`wget --output-document=- http://www.tip.it/runescape/grand-exchange-centre 2>/dev/null \
| grep "The Grand Exchange updated" | ./cleaner.rb`

Gives you: "The Grand Exchange updated 1 days, 13 hours, 0 minutes and 56 seconds ago"

Comment: I'm using cygwin on Windows is it still possible to install gem? What does gem do exactly?